# Gitlab-CI multi project pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a gitlab job that is trying to trigger a downstream pipeline from another project. The 2 project are at the same location. The problem is that the trigger job stays in pending mode, never triggering the correct pipeline. The job is has follow :

```
    trigger_test:
        stage: Test
        trigger:
           project: Name with space/nameWithoutSpace/ProjectToTrigger
```

The field project is supposed to be the full path to the project so I tried exactly that but I don't know if the spaces in the name affects it or not. I tried with "" but It didn't work. None of the projects are private so they should be able to access themselves.

I have no rights to access the projects configs so it makes it hard. Maybe it is because of my access rights? Any tips will be welcomed!

**EDIT** Secustor got it right. Using the project slug that i found in the url of my project I wanted to trigger worked for me.

Comment: Usually references in Gitlab are project slugs, have you already tried it in this case? The easiest way to get the slug is to go to the target repository and look at the URL bar of your Browser. It should look like this `https://your-gitlab.instance/a-namespace/the-target-project/`. `a-namespace/the-target-project` is your project slug in this context.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you very much it was that